# Limit the bit rate of my wifi adpter

Tags: linux, wifi, nmcli

I'm using laird ST60 USB wifi adapter.
I used the nmcli command to check my bit rate and it shows 270Mbit/s:
[image]

This baud rate is really heavy on my USB bandwidth when I actually only need like 50Mbit/s, is there any way to limit this rate? I tried to look also on the driver and couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's not how USB works. USB will always run at one and the same speed, and since your Wifi speed will not affect how much data you want to transport in total, that data will always be exactly the same load on your USB bus. So, maybe tell us why you come up with the rather surprising statement "is really heavy on my USB bandwidth".

Comment: Hi, Marcus. I use 4 USB cameras and the wifi adapter on 1 USB2 hub. I need the ability to run those cameras and the Wifi adapter disturbs them. When I connect a LAN-USB cable everything works fine.

Comment: USB cameras usually use isochronous transfers and hence have guaranteed data rate. Again, USB doesn't care about your Wifi rate. it always works the same speed. If you have 1 MB of data to receive or send via wifi, it will always occupy the USB for the same amount of time. This sounds like one of your USB devices, quite possibly an integrated hub or the xHCI, is misbehaving. You can't fix that through reducing your wifi rate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Reducing wi-fi speed will allow more frequent idle time on the USB bus to be used for devices other than the wi-fi adapter

Comment: @user253751 again, cameras usually use the isochronous transfer method, so that they get a guaranteed bandwidth, so that really doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarcusMüller How can someone check whether their camera uses isochronous transfer?

Comment: @user253751 run `lsusb -v` and look for "Transfer Type"; note that this is per end-point, for some devices; not sure when during the endpoint lifetime this has to be set.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what you say. Is there any way maybe to limit it on the linux's wifi driver?